# Are SignalR connection IDs cryptographically secure?

Tags: signalr

It looks as if SignalR uses GUIDs as the connection ID for clients

> Although the behavior can be modified, the framework will use a GUID by default:

[[ref, page 30]](http://eduardopires.net.br/Repositorio/SignalR_eBook.pdf)

And we are told that if a person can guess another client's connection ID then they can impersonate them.

> You should never pass one client's connection id to other clients, as
>   a malicious user could use it to mimic a request from that client.

[[ref]](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/security/hub-authorization)

Are these connection ID GUIDs cryptographically secure/random? If not it would seem like a (blazingly obvious) security hole.

Answer (score 0):

I think the client must always send its identifier to the server. A good way to make that more secure could be to use the WSS instead of WS for websocket and Https instead of http for the fallbacks.

Does it make sense?

Comment: Thankyou imperugo, but I am concerned about attackers guessing the connection ID, not from them sniffing it. If they are able to sniff it then it wouldn't matter if it was generated in an unguessable way.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [signalr documentation](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/introduction-to-security#connectiontoken), connection ids are sent as part of a connection token which is encrypted. They use DPAPI data protection for encryption. As such, connection ids don't need to be securely generated and [aren't](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/1fba14fa3437e24c204dfaf8a18db3fce8acad3c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/PersistentConnection.cs#L504).
The fact that the signalr documentation on security (same as above) states that they should not be shared is confusing for me too.

> Because the connection id is part of the verification process, you should not reveal one user's connection id to other users or store the value on the client, such as in a cookie.

Not sure what to make of this. Based on the code it should be safe to share connection ids, since tokens are encrypted. You can see the encryption/decryption/check in the same class where the id is generated (second link).